# erase_results and retry in rails 3.1.3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

The below code works in Rails 2.3.5, but I cannot get it to work in Rails 3.1.3:

```
rescue ActionController::DoubleRenderError
  erase_results
  retry
end
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

erase_results was deprecated in [Rails 2.3.8](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/erase_results). You may want to try another option depending on what you are looking to do.